# Use Application Server based User management or Custom User management?

Tags: security, java-ee-6

I'm following the Java EE 6 tutorial and I'm reading the part related to [security](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijrp.html).

In the examples, the user management is done [using the features provided with the Glassfish server](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbxr/index.html). Is this the usual method used to manage users in Java EE?

Is it possible to use mechanisms such as e-mail based user account creation (password sent via email) etc. by using this method? If not, what alternative mechanism/library do you recommend for user account management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/foo/entry/mort_learns_jdbc_for_glassfish).